# #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h> not found IOS objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, import, facebook-sdk-4.0

seem a bit old question but I have try some solution but did not work. I doubt that is because old Facebook frame work is not working anymore. I have a `Objective-C` project that use `FacebookSDK`. I have copied `FacebookSDK.framework` into project folder and add using target-build phrase - link binary with binaries. I tried to clean and build the project but still got error `#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>` file not found. Is there any solution for this issue? many thanks? By the way how to check version facebookSDK and see whether I need to migrate to new updated version?

Comment: Are you able to find 'Framework Search Paths' in your build settings?

Comment: hi my 'Framework Search Paths' in target is $(PROJECT_DIR); $(inherited) and in project is blank. Problem is that i can still import other dependence and pod file also

Comment: Can you right-click on the framework in your project and select 'reveal in finder' and verify that the framework is actually in your project directory? Also, does it say `recursive` next to $(PROJECT_DIR) or $(inherited)?

Comment: you mean right click framework-show in finder? Here is my screenshot http://tinypic.com/r/2lk9m6p/9

Comment: That seems right. What about 'Header Search Paths'?

Comment: hi my 'Header Search Paths' for target is here http://tinypic.com/r/2rh1sub/9 and for project is blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Cocoapods i would suggest to update your `FacebookSDK`

to the latest with adding those 3 dependencies :

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

then  a `Pod Install` from terminal to download the frameworks and finally do some changes since the new sdk is different .

Comment: thanks a lot. Do you have any reference link for any change that should be made? do we still use #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>?

Comment: the latest sdk facebook make a change its shared to 3 new sdk login , core , share so developers if they want to perform just a login with fb they dont need to download all the sdk . now u can import sdk like this : 

#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>

Comment: For more details check the official Developer guide for FBSDK :

[Facebookdoc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios)

Comment: thanks i try our way to import 3 facebook sdk but there're a problem with this method - (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error; say "expect a type"!